# Closing custom tab on item context change

Tags: content-editor, sheer-ui

I have a custom button in content editor that will trigger a command that will run the following code(simplified for this purpose)

```
SheerResponse.Eval((new ShowEditorTab()
            {
                Command = "mycommand:acommand",
                Header = "Header",
                Title = "Title",
                Url = urlString.ToString(),
                Id = idOfTab,
                Closeable = true
            }).ToString());
```

This works fine as it opens a custom tab in content editor but when I change the context item(by selecting a different item in the content tree) the tab stays there. With this approach is there an easy way to close the tab upon changing the context item?

I could not find any property in ShowEditorTab to inject a callback to close it or anything like that.